# Grant Privileges for TEMP Table(dynamically created by a Stored Proc)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, google-cloud-sql

1. List item Initially a **TEMP table created by a Stored Procedure**, which does some ACTIONS
2. There are these several TEMP tables thus created by this above said SP.
3. I want to give **SELECT** permission for some of my **SQL Users** for these **TEMP tables** which was dynamically created by the above **SP's**

For the above req, I tried the below query from a **ROOT user to give permission for the table with the prefix temp**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  dbname .`Temp%` TO  'TEST'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But, still the above privileges for the user 'TEST' can't able to SELECT these TEMP tables and gves the below err:

> SELECT command denied to user 'TEST'@'localhost' for table
>   'temp_ccdata_20140904101131_2'

pls anyone suggest if there are any possibilities **to grant SELECT access for the dynamic tables created by a Stored Procedure**

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Check [13.7.1.4 GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html): `The "_" and "%" wildcards are permitted when specifying database names in GRANT statements that grant privileges at the global or database levels.`

Comment: hi, is there any other possibility to give grant SELECT permission using wild card for the dynamic tables.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @wchiquito, the `_` and `%` wilcards are permitted when specifying database names. A possible workaround for using wildcards in the table name of a `GRANT` query follows:

```
SELECT CONCAT('GRANT SELECT ON dbname.', TABLE_NAME, ' TO user;')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'prefix%';
```

Replacing `dbname` with `exampledb`, `user` with `tony42` and `prefix` with `foo_` should return queries like:

```
GRANT SELECT ON exampledb.foo_usertable TO tony42
```

You can then use these execute these queries to achieve the permission changes you seek. It may not be the most elegant but will get the job done. Also, you may want to wrap the names in back ticks to account for spaces and such.